# preg_replace with function

Tags: php, preg-replace, urlencode

I have some HTML that is being run through PHP:

`<a href="?char=">&</a>`

and I'm wanting to use a `preg_replace` to replace the first `&` with a `urlencode`d value of it.  However:

`preg_replace("/char=\">(.*?)<\/a>/", "char=".urlencode("$1")."\">$1</a>", $links);`

But this gives me the value `$1`, instead of the expected back-reference.  How can I do what I'm trying to do (make the output look like `<a href="?char=%26">&</a>`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modifier `e` in your regexp or use the function `preg_replace_callback` (see the doc) instead.

Comment: Note that when using `/e`, the replacement script fragment needs to be a string to prevent it from being interpreted before the call to preg_replace: `preg_replace('/.../e', '"char=" . urlencode("$1") . "\\">$1</a>"', $links);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both **e** modifier and **preg_replace_callback** function approaches can do the job.
I personally prefer one-line decision:

> preg_replace("/char=\">(.*?)</a>/e",
>   '"char=".urlencode("$1")."\\">$1"',
>   $links);