# Replace custom tag with anchor tag using preg_replace

Tags: php

I want to replace `<cast>Test Cast</cast>` with `<a href="www.example.com/cast/test-cast">Test Cast</a>`.

```
function replace_synopsis_tags($short_synopsis) {

        $pattern = '/<cast>(.+?)<\/cast>/i';
        $replacement = "<a href='".base_url()."casts/".str_replace(" ","-",strtolower("$1"))."'>$1</a>";
        $short_synopsis = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $short_synopsis);


        return $short_synopsis;
    }

    $synopsis = "<cast>Test Cast</cast>";
    echo replace_synopsis_tags($synopsis);
```

What is being returned is `<a href="www.example.com/cast/Test Cast">Test Cast</a>`

How do I solve?

Comment: You can't use `$1` outside the replacement string. You need to use `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_replace with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710764/preg-replace-with-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument, its way much more efficient for the job.

Online Eval : https://3v4l.org/0l9hT

```
$html = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<cast>cast-test</cast>
<cast>cast two !</cast>
</body>
</html>";

function castTags(string $html)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $casts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('cast');
    while($cast = $casts->item(0)) {
        $value = $cast->nodeValue;
        $link = $dom->createElement('a');
        $link->setAttribute('href', "www.example.com/cast/" . rawurlencode(str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($value))));
        $link->nodeValue = $value;
        $cast->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $cast);
    }
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}

echo castTags($html); 
// <!DOCTYPE html> 
// <html>
//     <body>
//         <a href="www.example.com/cast/cast-test">cast-test</a>
//         <a href="www.example.com/cast/cast-two-%21">cast two !</a>
//     </body>
// </html>
```

Comment: only issue i have with dom parsing is the frequency of having to work with bad html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.5 or lower, you could simply add the `\e` modifier, and your script would work fine. However, if you're using PHP 7, you'll need to use [`preg-replace-callback()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead. PHP 7 no longer supports the `\e` modifier.

Your script can be updated to use `preg_replace_callback()` for compatibility with PHP 7:

```
function replace_synopsis_tags($short_synopsis) {

    $pattern = '/<cast>(.+?)<\/cast>/i';
    $replacement = function($matches) { return "<a href='".base_url()."casts/".str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($matches[1]))."'>".$matches[1]."</a>"; };
    $short_synopsis = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replacement, $short_synopsis);

    return $short_synopsis;
}

$synopsis = "<cast>Test Cast</cast>";
echo replace_synopsis_tags($synopsis);
```

---

From the changelog of [`preg-replace`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> As of PHP 5.5.0 **E_DEPRECATED** level error is emitted when passing in the "\e" modifier. As of PHP 7.0.0 **E_WARNING** is emitted in this case and "\e" modifier has no effect.

In PHP 5.4, you could have used this pattern:

```
$pattern = '/<cast>(.+?)<\/cast>/ie'; // with trailing e
```

Comment: was the op ever using \e ?

Comment: @smith No, but that was the missing ingredient for their code not working **if** they were using PHP 5.5 or lower. I'm not sure I made that clear enough in my answer.

Comment: sorry just confused as to why half the answer is talking about not doing something that the OP was not doing in the first place,

Comment: @smith No it's a valid point, and after reading my answer again, it really isn't clear why I focused on it so much. I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify my point.

Comment: probably in bigger trouble if your still using an unsupported php version, nice edit.

Comment: @smith I agree, I'd hope the Op is using PHP 7 by now, but I've mentioned fixes for both versions either way.